# Laravel Storage link is wrong

Tags: laravel, storage

In Nova I can see the following link for my image `https://mydomain.be/storage/87/Exclusive-%281%29.png`, this link is working when I browse to it.

However in my blade when outputting `Storage::url($product->image)` I'm getting the following `/storage/dHdZe7qkzMvq97iaoPVhao1oKHe9dWWoglSehgDA.jpeg"` which is giving me a 404.

The storage folder is linked, so in my /public folder I have a symlink to storage/app/public, and it has all these folders

[image]

Am I missing something?
This is an older version of Laravel: 6.x.

Thank you

Comment: Have you used Storage::url($product->image) with in asset(Storage::url($product->image))